# Store html content into php variable?

Tags: php, database

I have some html in my php page that I fetched from database and will be used many times in my webpage, so I want to put it into a php variable for later use.

My sample code is

```
<div class="info">
  Some content from database here...
  <div class="more">
     Some more text...
  </div>
</div>
```

How to store this html into php variable?

Please also tell me how to echo content of that variable?

Comment: Say hello to [PHP strings](http://php.net/string).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You should do some research, give something a go and then come back when you've hit a wall and ask a question that is a [mcve]. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Jon Stirling but You can do like below:

```
$htmlData = '<div class="info">
  Some content from database here...
  <div class="more">
     Some more text...
  </div>
</div>';
```

and you can print this

```
echo $htmlData;
```